# generate salted wordpress hash

Tags: wordpress, hash, salt

i'm new to wordpress field

So this is a salted wordpress hash :

`$1$4Dad4CM6$I63lezzBCDjK9RhBwUgZi1`

How can i generate hashes like that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to generate a hash for Wordpress?

Comment: This is very vague, where did you get the hash? What is it used for? Why do you want one?

Comment: what do you mean by vague? why? i got from the .htpasswd file

Comment: Wordpress doesn't create an .htpasswd file - are you sure you haven't just set the directory to be protected via your panel? Just google '.htpasswd generator'

Comment: ok thank you :) and i guess it is md5 (apache servers)